# How i can change Agile Template to CMMI template in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have already done a new project with agile template then I figured out that I need the template to be (CMMI) template

the steps are , team >> team project collection settings >> Process template manager  :
I can't download CMMI template the download button is disabled and CMMI is (default) but when you open the work items it gives you agile work items

Is there any way I can do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change a team project from one process template to another process template. Assuming there's not much (or any) data in the team project, the fastest solution is to just delete it and recreate it using your preferred process template.

Comment: but i  can't download cmmi template because the button is disabled .

Comment: @JaNaSaadeddin That documentation is 8 years old and for TFS 2008. It is no longer relevant.